# Get Ubuntu-server usage through PHP on another server

Tags: php, linux, resources, cpu, ram

I have a couple of Linux-servers.
And I want one of them to display resource usage on the other ones.
For instance CPU-load, RAM (total, used and available) and so on.

What I am looking for is an PHP-class or similar that possibly might get the data from Webmin (installed on all servers) or maybe through SSH.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Elegant solution i can think of (one of many)

Install [zabbix](http://www.zabbix.com/) clients on servers you want to monitor.

Use this in your PHP:
http://zabbixapi.confirm.ch/

Answer (score 0):

Unless Webmin provides some sort of api type interface, you would have to login, via ssh, to each server and run a set of commands to get all the data. This can be done using `exec` or with ssh library in PHP.

A more efficient option would be to have all servers report relevant stats on an interval to a central database. Then you could query that database to get information on any of the stats you were looking for.